# Material Design AppCompat vs ActionBarSherloch

Tags: android, android-appcompat, actionbarsherlock

1. Какая разница между библиотеками `Material Design AppCompat` и
   `ActionBarSherloch`?
2. И какая из них лучше для применения?

Comment: первая от Google, де-факто стандарт (ведь в новых Android тот же встроен уже встроен), вторая Васи Пупкина. я пользовался только первой, раз де-факто стандарт - то весь дизайн рисуют под нее и экосистема у нее шире (проблема либо решена - либо ее решите вы и это будет ценно). но вторая возможно удобнее для юзера, ибо люди из Google не отличаются умением совпадать удобный UI/UX (в хроме много ошибок было, от которых сами отказались, и т.д.), может и другие + есть. смотреть надо и сопопставлять с задачей

Comment: no, avtor sam napisal v githube chto eto deprecated i chto ispolzovali AppCompat

Comment: и причем здесь качество библиотеки? люди часто имеют проблемы с самооценкой (а тут гугл сам навязывает монополию своих стандартов) и вообще никто не без тараканов в голове, может он еще и пьет или насвай жует, и что. посмотрите библиотеку, исследуйте и подумайте - вот это будет объективно

Comment: ya to posmotrel vse, no tut est` programmisty kotorye privykli k staromu. Na danny moment ya polzuyus app compat, i xotel prost posluwat vawi idei.

Comment: дело далеко не только в привычке. я когда впервые делал pull-to-refresh, я не имел опыта ни с вьюшкой от гугла ни со сторонней библиотекой, что осваивать мне без разницы, сперва даже хотел первую - название красивое и поновее вроде, но, рассмотрев обе в работе, заказчик предпочел вторую, и я тоже его поддержал чисто с позиции юзера. навязывание гуглом своих решений как единственно-правильных - это маразм, и, я думаю, кроме яндекса и дураков никто этому не следует, а выбирает по ситуации. вы не дурак?

Comment: xaaxxaax, xotel im ne byt' ))). Vse je. eto vawe mneniye, ne tak li?

Comment: нет, это результаты моих исследований. много работаю. когда что-то неэргономичное этому мешает - я это замечаю и ругаюсь вслух, от "бардак" до отборного мата. затем, когда я реализую аналогичное (а реализовать рано или поздно приходится абсолютно все, вплоть до плагинов для IDE и своей сборки хромиума для своих спец. задач), я не допускаю ошибок, которые выявил. кроме того, собираю статистику и с других пользователей, там каждый клик отсылается мне на сервер, и я вижу, где пользователь нажал не то что хотел, где замешкался из-за непонятного UI и т.д. - зачастую все совпадает с моим.

Comment: moment:"там каждый клик отсылается мне на сервер" - kokoy tool vy tut ispol'zuete? mojete skinut kakoy nibud link esli ne sekret ;)